# How to solve the following second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to solve the following problem and got a solution in terms of the complementary error function, but it doesn't satisfy the first boundary condition.

$$\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2} - a y(x) = b \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

where

$$g(x) = \delta(x - c), \qquad \lim_{x\to\infty} {y(x)} = 0, \qquad y'(0)=0, \qquad a>0$$

Comment: Yes, I have typed the second boundary condition above. I am trying to solve a heat conduction problem starting from a specific time at which the temperature distribution at that time is described by Heaviside unit step function.

Comment: You should mention what you have tried. Otherwise, I don't think people will be keen to give a hand. Are you sure the condition is $y(\infty) = 0$ and not $y(0)=0$?

Comment: Actually, I have tried and got a solution in terms of the complementary error function, However, I have a problem to satisfy the outer boundary condition.

Comment: Yes, a is always greater than zero.

Comment: Yes. I have revised it again.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing,

$$\ddot x (t) - a \, x (t) = b \, \dot\delta (t - c)$$

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides,

$$\big( s^2 - a \big) \, \hat x (s) = \underbrace{\dot x_0}_{=0} + x_0 s + b \,s \, e^{-cs} = x_0 s + b \,s \, e^{-cs}$$

and, thus,

$$\hat x (s) = x_0 \left(\frac{s}{s^2 - a}\right) + b \left(\frac{s}{s^2 - a} \right) e^{-cs}$$

Taking the inverse Laplace transform,

$$x (t) = \begin{cases} x_0 \cosh \big(\sqrt{a} \, t \big) & \text{ if } 0 \le t \le c^-\\\\ x_0 \cosh \big(\sqrt{a} \, t \big) + b \cosh \big( \sqrt{a} \, (t-c) \big) & \text{ if } t \ge c^+\end{cases}$$

Note that $x$ is **discontinuous**, as it "jumps" $b$ at time $t=c$.

Comment: What about the other boundary condition at $y(\infty)=0$?

Comment: The OP can worry about it. I won't spend more time on this until the OP answers my comment-question.

Comment: This boundary condition is correct. It means the change of temperature at the outer boundary of an infinite extended layer should be zero which seems logical.

Comment: @RefaatGalal Are you 100% sure you typed the ODE correctly? The solution seems non-physical.

Comment: Yes, I have revised it again.

Comment: @RefaatGalal A hyperbolic cosine seems non-physical.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Is it allowable to solve the ODE by using Method of Variation of Parameters?

Comment: @RefaatGalal I suppose it is, but the solution should be the same.